# Flutter - How to handle loading of images that may not exist

Tags: flutter, url, exception, error-handling, image-loading

Is there any way to handle image url that not containt an image by using CachedNetworkImage package?

This is my code and when I do images loading, these errors are always popping up

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => BookErrorImage(),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
```

[[image]]

Comment: can you show what you are getting in `imageUrl`

Comment: sr for my late response, this is that error imageUrl: https://covers.feedbooks.net/book/6867.jpg?size=large

Comment: when i try to view image,it doesn't show anything,when you get image from server try to access from browser if it is available in the browser also it doesn't show either with image.network it is the problem with image also make sure it is available